# Functional programming / Ramda: Creating a new object by picking nested properties

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Functional programming newbie here. I have this object:

```
{ 
  _id: '2014d5db-55dc-4078-ae87-382c226d0785',
  _source: { 
    phone: '00447827434313',
    ...
  } 
}
```

In the end I want to have it in this format:

```
{ 
  id: '2014d5db-55dc-4078-ae87-382c226d0785',
  phone: '00447827434313',
  ...
}
```

Basically extracting `_source`, and renaming `_id` to `id`.

I created this function below which works, but I'm trying use only Ramda's functions instead of creating new objects by hand. I assume it's more "functional" way, let me know if it doesn't really matter.

```
const test = o => merge(o._source, { id: o._id })
```

Thanks very much

Comment: Will your output always be flat like that? (I.e. no nested properties?)

Comment: @ScottSauyet Ideally yes. I just want to have whatever inside `_source`, and add the `_id` on top, renamed as `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a particular built-in Ramda function for that.  But it's not hard to write one on top of `lensPath`, `view`, and `map`:

```
const remap = R.curry((desc, obj) => R.map(path => R.view(R.lensPath(path), obj), desc));

const myExtract = remap({
  id: ['_id'],
  phone: ['_source', 'phone']
});

myExtract(input);
//=> {"id": "2014d5db-55dc-4078-ae87-382c226d0785", "phone": "00447827434313"}
```

It only works this simply if your output is described as a flat list of fields (of course their properties could themselves be objects.)  But one where you pulled from nested paths and pushed to nested paths would not be too much harder to write.  The user API would be uglier, though, I imagine.

I don't see any clean way to make this points-free and still retain readability.  Perhaps someone else might manage that, but I think this is already pretty nice.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20input%20%3D%20%7B%20%0A%20%20_id%3A%20%272014d5db-55dc-4078-ae87-382c226d0785%27%2C%0A%20%20_source%3A%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20phone%3A%20%2700447827434313%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20address%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20street%3A%20%27123%20Main%20Street%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20city%3A%20%27Anytown%27%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%20%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20remap%20%3D%20R.curry%28%28desc%2C%20obj%29%20%3D%3E%20R.map%28path%20%3D%3E%20R.view%28R.lensPath%28path%29%2C%20obj%29%2C%20desc%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20myExtract%20%3D%20remap%28%7B%0A%20%20id%3A%20%5B%27_id%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20phone%3A%20%5B%27_source%27%2C%20%27phone%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20city%3A%20%5B%27_source%27%2C%20%27address%27%2C%20%27city%27%5D%0A%7D%29%3B%0A%0AmyExtract%28input%29)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ScottSauyet, this is very helpful. Do you agree my `test()` function isn't the functional way of doing it? I just want to make sure it's fair for me to look for something else

Comment: I don't think there's a single answer to that.  Yours is the most straightforward way, and if you don't need anything more reusable, why not just go ahead with it?  If you expect to reuse it with different fields being mapped, my suggestion might be an improvement.  And if you want to map into more complex structures, then you need something still more sophisticated.  The only downside to your original is that it might include fields you *don't* want to include from `source`.  If that's not a concern, it's a perfectly valid solution on its own.